# Counting objects without RTTI

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, polymorphism

I'm having a problem that makes me feel rather daft. In a hobby project, I have a std::list of  pointers to an interface class, which point to various concrete implementations of said interface.

For example, say I have the following:

```
class Seafood ...
class Fishstick : public Seafood ...
class Squid : public Seafood ...
...
std::list<Seafood*> buffet;
```

Now that I have my buffet populated by different seafood items, I want to count the number of fishsticks i have available to see if more needs to be ordered from the kitchen.

How would I do this without RTTI or some devious implementation thereof? I've read some articles that claim that if you find yourself wanting to use RTTI, you are approaching OOP the wrong way and/or your solution should be re-engineered. Are there some patterns or other solutions that deal with this problem? Which I'm sure has to surfaced many times before.

I was thinking the obvious which is some kind of virtual function, but I can't figure out how to do this without building in a cheesy version of RTTI, or some knowledge about descendants into the interface (CountIfFishstick / IsFishstick / Is(type)).

edit: one other thing that came to mind would be to keep one list of fishsticks, one list of squid, etc. But that would surely defeat the whole purpose of interface/implemetation.

Comment: As you said there is a small code smell here: either you care about the particular types (which you seem to) or you don't care (use the interface). Note that polymorphism is not about being able to store them together in a container, but rather being able to use the derived types through a fixed interface (say when calling functions), so you might want to keep them separate (for counting purposes) and yet use the interface or other purposes.

Comment: If you absolutely must check the type of the variable to determine its nature, `bool isFishstick = !!dynamic_cast<Fishstick *>(value);` ought to work. That said, you should look for other approaches to this problem.

Comment: It's actually rather silly to be all scared of RTTI and such.  A smell does not indicate bad design, it indicates that there MAY BE bad design.  While polymorphism is about treating thing the same, it is sometimes necessary, such as when counting concrete types, to dig into the inheritance higherarchy.  Doing this rather than some other convoluted thing is very ofter the simplest and best way to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want some variant of the visitor pattern.  There are many and it's hard to say which you want.  I might recommend getting *Modern C++ Design* and reviewing Alexendrescu's implementation.  Otherwise, google "visitor pattern" and you'll get 1000 km of links to read.

Comment: I can accept this as an answer in 4 minutes, but yes. This pattern would work beautifully. I will expand on my question to answer it with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

[Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) is what you're looking for. There's also a special version of visitor, called [Acyclic visitor](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/acv.pdf) which uses RTTI to solve some of the issues with the original visitor, so RTTI is not always wrong, but it *can* lead to horrible code unless you really know what you're doing...

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have a `name` function in the base class to return the name of the item, so you can display it to the kitchen. Just use that to index into a map of item counts.

In general you can provide a function that returns any unique identifier per each class.

Answer (score 1):

How about Composite Pattern? Buffet is really a collection of seafood collections. FishStick and Squid are "Component"s in Composite pattern which will maintain their count of items. So when Buffet is list, it can traverse and call count on Composites.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++11 you could do something like:

```
int num_fish_sticks = std::count_if(buffer.begin(), buffet.end(),
    [](const SeaFood* sf) {sf->is_fish_stick()});
```

You would need to declare a pure virtual function in SeaFood:

```
virtual bool is_fish_stick() const = 0;
```

and implement it accordingly in the subclasses.

**EDIT:** Of course, this may be messy if you have too many subclasses. In that case, you would be better just with RTTI:

```
int num_fish_sticks = std::count_if(buffer.begin(), buffet.end(),
    [](const SeaFood* sf) {typeid(*sf) == typeid(Fishstick)});
```

Comment: This is even worse than using RTTI.

Comment: @AndreasMagnusson well, the OP wanted a solution without using RTTI. I'll update my answer to include a more generic way, using RTTI.

Comment: Yup, for a good solution see mine and Crazy Eddies responses. The visitor-pattern is a way to "add" new virtual functions to a class-hierarchy without changing the original classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is much more basic than you're making it seem: at least as you've presented it, there doesn't seem to be much (any?) reason to use inheritance here at all.

Inheritance is useful when your objects have different *behaviors*, but in this case it would appear that they all have essential the same behavior -- in fact, pretty much no behavior at all (unless count "play dead").

If I were going to model a buffet, I probably *would* use containers. Each tray on your hot-table is a container holding some amount of something. If you want, you can model the table as a container of trays, and (possibly) the room as a container of tables.

Each tray holds a "food item" (or whatever you prefer to call it), for which you mostly have a name and a quantity. The sole behavior might be a timer dealing with when the food was "served", and based on that when any remaining needs to be removed. You *might* have a bit more than that, such as separating the foods into those available only as part of a full meal, vs. those available as to those who've only purchased access to the salad bar.